# Hibernate Search: searchable and sortable on the same field

Tags: hibernate-search

I am using hibernate search 5.11.1 and need to support searchable and sortable on the same field of type String. After reading through the [reference guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#_metadata_api), I found the following documentation about using Normalizers to sort analyzed text.

**Reference from the official guide:**

> Analyzers are great when you need to search in text documents, but
>   what if you want to sort the analyzed text? Then you’re in for a bit
>   of trouble, because analyzed text is multi-valued: when indexing a
>   book with the title "Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing
>   Code", the analyzed title is in fact the (unordered) set
>   {"refactoring", "improving", "design", "existing", "code"}. If you
>   tried to sort on the title after such an analysis, any of those words
>   could be used, so your book could end up in the D’s (because of
>   "design"), or in the R’s (because of "refactoring"), or in the E’s,
>   etc.
>
> So in the end, you probably don’t want your fields to be tokenized
>   when you sort on those fields. Normalizers solve exactly this issue:
>   they are analyzers, but without a tokenizer, and with some runtime
>   checks that prevent the analysis to produce multiple tokens, thereby
>   ensuring your sorts will always be consistent.
>
> Hibernate Search provides normalizer equivalent for relevant analyzer
>   annotations: @Normalizer, @NormalizerDef, @NormalizerDefs. As with
>   analyzer, you can use implementations directly (for instance
>   @Normalizer(impl = MyCollactionKeyAnalyzer.class)) or named
>   normalizers (for instance @Normalizer(definition = "myNormalizer")
>   with @NormalizerDef(filters = @TokenFilterDef(factory =
>   LowerCaseFilterFactory.class)).

Based on the above,  I wrote the following code:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@AnalyzerDef(name = "en", tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),
        filters = {
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class)
        })
@NormalizerDef(name = "lowercase", filters = {
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class),
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class)
        }
)
@Table(name = "ORDER")
public class Order {

    //Some other fields that are omitted for brevity here

    @Field(name = "orderName_Search", store = Store.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "en"))
    @Field(name = "orderName_Sort", store = Store.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO, normalizer = @Normalizer(definition = "lowercase"))
    @SortableField(forField = "orderName_Sort")
    @Column(name = "ORDER_NAME")
    private String orderName;

}
```

However, it does not seem to work as I ran into the following error.

**[ERROR] com.appnexus.konnect.web.exceptions.ConnectExceptionHandler - Exception
org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: Cannot automatically determine the field type for field 'orderName'. Use byField(String, Sort.Type) to provide the sort type explicitly**

My question is where it went wrong? It works when only using either @Field annotation but fails when using both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, it seems you wrote something like this:

```
qb.sort().byField("orderName").createSort()
```

But the field `orderName` does not exist as far as Hibernate Search is concerned. Only `orderName_Search` and `orderName_Sort` exist. In this case you should write:

```
qb.sort().byField("orderName_Sort").createSort()
```

Also, be aware that setting `analyze = Analyze.NO` on `orderName_Sort` will effectively disable your normalizer. You probably want to leave that out.

Comment: Yes, you are exactly right! Even about the part you guessed what I did. Thank you detective @yrodiere!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with Hibernate Search 6, I too was trying to sort by the field name. E.g.

`@FullTextField(analyzer = "custom_analyzer") @GenericField(name = "story_sort", sortable = Sortable.YES)`

However, I realized I needed to replace "story" with "story_sort" in the sort function:

`SearchResult<Story> result = searchSession.search(Story.class).where( f -> f.match().field("story").matching(param)).sort( f -> f.field( "story_sort" //was "story" before).desc()).fetch(offset,5);`